# How to resolve circular reference in JSON serializing?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Help me, please, to store tree structure in JSON format. I got

```
ERROR 6444 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].    [dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:912) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._doFindSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1260) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._findSuperInterfaceChain(TypeFactory.java:1254) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    // more stacktrace here...
```

on the folowing code:

```
public class CustomASTNode implements ASTNode {
    private final CustomNode node; // simple property
    private final ASTNodeID id; // simple property
    @JsonBackReference
    private final ASTNode parent; // circular property!
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ASTNode> children = new ArrayList<>(); // circular property!
    // more code
}

public interface ASTNode extends Iterable<ASTNode> { // ?
    // more code
}
```

I used `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` annotations to deal with fields, but have no ideas how to resolve recursion in interface. Is it possible or maybe it is necessary to rewrite these snippet?

Comment: If there's a circular reference, it's not a tree.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, but I am talking about circular reference in interface definition (`ASTNode extends Iterable<ASTNode>`), while tree is built from `CustomASTNode` objects using `parent` and `children` fields

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying your ASTNode's form a graph with cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity

> A simple example would be:
>
> ```
> @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
> public class Identifiable
> {
>     public int value;
>
>     public Identifiable next;
> }
> ```
>
> and if we created a cycle consisting of two values, like:
>
> ```
> Identifiable ob1 = new Identifiable();
> ob1.value = 13;
> Identifiable ob2 = new Identifiable();
> ob2.value = 42;
> // link as a cycle:
> ob1.next = ob2;
> ob2.next = ob1;
> ```
>
> and serialized using:
>
> ```
> String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ob1);
> ```
>
> we would get following serialization for JSON:
>
> ```
> {
>     "@id" : 1,
>     "value" : 13,
>     "next" : {
>         "@id" : 2,
>         "value" : 42,
>         "next" : 1
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation with removing `extends Iterable<ASTNode>` from interface definition solve problems.